# Focus+context via brushing mouseovers zoom issue

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, zooming

Complete code is in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67tpvh16/2/).
The problem is when zooming mouseovers in the top and bottom chart do not match, i.e. moving circles in the bottom should not go beyond the area that is selected via brushing. I'm updating the moving points as follows:

```
  focus.on "mousemove", () ->
     xPos = d3.mouse(this)[0]
     updateMovingPoints(xPos)
  context.on "mousemove", () ->
     xPos = d3.mouse(this)[0]
     updateMovingPoints(xPos)
```

[image]

As you see, the bottom mouseovers do not match with top chart, i.e. go beyond zoomed area.

Comment: Added a picture to make it easier to understand.

Comment: At a glance, it looks like you're not using the correct scales to convert between mouse points and data values.  If the mouse is over the main graph, a give `xPos` will have a different meaning than if the mouse is over the focus graph, and you're not passing that information to the `updateMovingPoints` method.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll try to use different scales for bottom chart on mouseover.

Comment: I would take a slightly different approach. The zoom area will always correspond to the width of the chart above. When zoomed,  I would get the mouse xPos relative to the left side of the zoom area, and then calculate the upper chart xPos from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution essentially uses AmeliaBR's suggestion to convert the xPos from one x-scale to the other, which I do using using `xScale(xScale2.invert(xPos))`, and then passing this modified x position to `updateMovingPoints`

`scale.invert` on a D3 time scale gets back the date from the original data (docs [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#invert)), which we can promptly re-scale, to convert to an SVG x-coordinate using a different scale

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/pusauc5q/10/

First I split the `updateMovingPoints` function into two `updateMovingPointsTop` and `updateMovingPointsbottom`, because updating on the bottom (context) chart is always going to be easy, while updating top (focus) is the tricky bit.

```
  updateMovingPointsTop = (xPos) ->    
    focusLine1 = focus.select(".line1").attr("d", line1(data))
    focusLine2 = focus.select(".line2").attr("d", line2(data))
    updatePointPosition(xPos, focusLine1, focusCircles[0])
    updatePointPosition(xPos, focusLine2, focusCircles[1])

  updateMovingPointsBottom = (xPos) ->      
    contextLine1 = context.select(".line1").attr("d", line3(data))
    contextLine2 = context.select(".line2").attr("d", line4(data))
    updatePointPosition(xPos, contextLine1, contextCircles[0])
    updatePointPosition(xPos, contextLine2, contextCircles[1])
```

Then, only when mousemoving on the bottom (context), I wanted to do some calculation to find  how the bottom `xPos` should be translated into the top x-scale:

```
updateMovingPointsTop(calculatexPosTop(xPos))
```

The `calculatexPosTop` function itself has some comments to explain. But basically it translates `xPos` from the bottom x-scale to the top x-scale, and sets to the min \ max of extents of that top scale if it lies outside the bounds. The bounds are calculated from the `range` when the scale is defined:

```
# The min and max extents (x coords) of the 'context' (top chart)
xScaleTopRange = xScale.range()
minExtent = xScaleTopRange[0]
maxExtent = xScaleTopRange[1]
```

And the key `calculatexPosTop` function looks like this:

```
# When mousemoving on the bottom chart, calculate where the equivaluent point is on the top chart
calculatexPosTop = (xPos) ->  
  # The translation of the 'context' x-scale (xScale2) to the 'focus' x-scale (xScale)
  # Note that when there's no zooming, xScale and xScale2 are the same so xPosInFocusScale = xPos
  xPosInFocusScale = xScale(xScale2.invert(xPos))
  # Check if the translated point lies outside the extents of the focus scale's range
  if xPosInFocusScale < minExtent
    minExtent
  else if xPosInFocusScale > maxExtent
    maxExtent
  else
    xPosInFocusScale
```

**EDIT**

I realised I was missing part of the solution: When zoomed in, moving along the top chart was not keeping the points within the brushed area. Fiddle link now updated with this fix.

This involved adding another function `calculatexPosBottom`, very similar to `calculatexPosTop`, but instead of using a `scale.range` to get the max and min extents, I use `brush.extent()` in the `brushed` function to find the 'size' of the brushed area:

```
# Get the x-limits of the brush
brushExtent = brush.extent()
# Convert using the x-scale to get SVG coordinates
minBrushExtent = xScale2(brushExtent[0])
maxBrushExtent = xScale2(brushExtent[1])
```

... and then I use the brush min \ max extents like this:

```
calculatexPosBottom = (xPos) ->  
  xPosInContextScale = xScale2(xScale.invert(xPos))
  # Check if there is no brushed area (ie the extent is [0, 0])
  # The brush extent is defined in the 'brushed' function
  if minBrushExtent == maxBrushExtent
    # If there is no brush, just use the same points on both scales
    xPos
  else if xPosInContextScale < minBrushExtent
    minBrushExtent
  else if xPosInContextScale > maxBrushExtent
    maxBrushExtent
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was also digging in the [direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654621/focuscontext-via-brushing-mouseovers-zoom-issue#comment40265081_25654621) proposed by AmeliaBR. So I think your post deserves a bounty since I've gathered some useful thoughts and approaches. Let's just wait a bit, maybe there're more insights or elegant solutions.

Comment: Thanks ovvn. I also feel there may be more elegance that can be achieved here, but it hasn't come to me yet! I've improved my approach a little (updated solution & fiddle link) so that I get the `brush.extent()` in a much more sensible way - only when the brushed area is redrawn (`brushed` function called) rather than every time the mouse moves! Should improve performance.